# Flex-Basis - Height of elements not accounting for images not immediately loaded

Tags: css, flexbox

(I know that this problem is well-documented in many instances, but I can't seem to find a work-around in my case.)

The problem is that flexbox elements toward the bottom of the page have insufficient height - presumably because the images inside those elements are loading slowly.

Here's an example: http://paleomagazine.com/paleo-websites-bloggers/

If you scroll down to the 3rd or 4th row of that page, you'll see that the elements are smushed together because of insufficient height.

I'm including my code below, but as a preface, I've tried to do a number of things through CSS and JS, including (a) using CSS transform and (b) trying to force a JS redraw (changing display, offsetHeight, and even webkitTransform).  None of this has worked (and if you check the page, you can see that it's still implemented for the moment).

```css
.custom-cat1 section.bSe {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-around;
}

.custom-cat1 section.bSe article.no-flex {
    flex-basis: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

.custom-cat1 section.bSe article.gdl {
    flex-basis: 30%;
    margin: 1rem .4rem;
    box-shadow: 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
}

.custom-cat1 section.bSe article.gdl .recipe-link-cover {
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    flex-direction: column;
    -webkit-box-pack: justify;
    justify-content: space-between;
    height: 100%;
}

.custom-cat1 .bSe article .awr {
    border: none;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    flex-direction: column;
    -webkit-box-pack: justify;
    height: 100%;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
}

.custom-cat1 .gdl h2.entry-title {
    font-size: 1.2em !important;
    margin-top: 0 !important;
    color: #444444;
}

.custom-cat1 .bSe article img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    max-width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto 10px auto;
    overflow: visible;
}

.custom-cat1 .bSe article img:hover,
.custom-cat1 .gdl h2.entry-title:hover {
    opacity: 0.8;
    transform: scale(1.04);
}

.custom-cat1 .bSe article .awr p {
    margin: 0 !important;
    line-height: 1.1em !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrp cnt gin custom-cat1">
    <section class="bSe fullWidth">
        <article class="no-flex">       
            <p id="breadcrumbs"><span xmlns:v="http://rdf.data-vocabulary.org/#"><span typeof="v:Breadcrumb"><a href="http://paleomagazine.com/" rel="v:url" property="v:title">Home</a> » <span rel="v:child" typeof="v:Breadcrumb"><a href="http://paleomagazine.com/paleo-diet/" rel="v:url" property="v:title">Paleo Diet</a> » <strong class="breadcrumb_last">Paleo Websites and Bloggers</strong></span></span></span></p>
            <div class="category-title">
                <h1><span>Paleo Websites and Bloggers</span></h1>
            </div>
            <div class="subheader-optin">
                <p>Ready to Get Started? <a><span class="tve-leads-two-step-trigger tl-2step-trigger-25517" style="display: inline;">Get Our Free 4-Week Paleo Meal Plan</span></a></p>
            </div>
        </article>
        <article class="gdl left" style="height: 450px;">
            <div class="awr">
                <h2 class="entry-title"><a href="http://paleomagazine.com/blogger-spotlight-eileen-laird">Blogger Spotlight – Eileen Laird</a></h2>                    
                <a href="http://paleomagazine.com/blogger-spotlight-eileen-laird"><img class="fwI" width="730" height="611" src="http://paleomagazine.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/Blogger-Spotlight-–-Eileen-Laird.jpg" alt="Blogger Spotlight – Eileen Laird" title="Blogger Spotlight – Eileen Laird"></a>
                <p>Eileen Laird is the founder of Phoenix Helix and author of A Simple Guide to the Paleo Autoimmune... <a href="http://paleomagazine.com/blogger-spotlight-eileen-laird">more</a></p>
            </div>
        </article>
        <div class="spr"></div>
        <article class="gdl left" style="height: 450px;">
            <div class="awr">
                <h2 class="entry-title"><a href="http://paleomagazine.com/blogger-spotlight-kaylie-johnson">Blogger Spotlight – Kaylie Johnson</a></h2>                    
                <a href="http://paleomagazine.com/blogger-spotlight-kaylie-johnson"><img class="fwI" width="730" height="611" src="http://paleomagazine.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/Blogger-Spotlight-Kaylie-Johnson.jpg" alt="Blogger Spotlight - Kaylie Johnson" title="Blogger Spotlight - Kaylie Johnson"></a>
                <p>Kaylie Johnson is the founder of Joyful Bite, where she shares her Paleo journey and amazing... <a href="http://paleomagazine.com/blogger-spotlight-kaylie-johnson">more</a></p>
            </div>
        </article>
        <div class="spr"></div>
        <article class="gdl left" style="height: 450px;">
            <div class="awr">
                <h2 class="entry-title"><a href="http://paleomagazine.com/paleo-blogger-stefani-ruper">Blogger Spotlight – Stefani Ruper</a></h2>                    
                <a href="http://paleomagazine.com/paleo-blogger-stefani-ruper"><img class="fwI" width="630" height="528" src="http://paleomagazine.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/Blogger-Spotlight-Stefani-Ruper.jpg" alt="Blogger Spotlight - Stefani Ruper" title="Blogger Spotlight - Stefani Ruper"></a>
                <p>1. What got you interested in the Paleo lifestyle? Back in 2009, I was a vegetarian on the verge of... <a href="http://paleomagazine.com/paleo-blogger-stefani-ruper">more</a></p>
            </div>
        </article>
        <div class="spr"></div>
        <article class="gdl left" style="height: 480px;">
            <div class="awr">
                <h2 class="entry-title"><a href="http://paleomagazine.com/paleo-blogger-mark-sisson">Blogger Spotlight – Mark Sisson</a></h2>                    
                <a href="http://paleomagazine.com/paleo-blogger-mark-sisson"><img class="fwI" width="630" height="528" src="http://paleomagazine.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/Blogger-Spotlight-Mark-Sisson.jpg" alt="Blogger Spotlight - Mark Sisson" title="Blogger Spotlight - Mark Sisson"></a>
                <p>1. What got you interested in the Paleo lifestyle? I was going through a major reevaluation of my... <a href="http://paleomagazine.com/paleo-blogger-mark-sisson">more</a></p>
            </div>
        </article>
        <div class="spr"></div>
        <article class="gdl left" style="height: 480px;">
            <div class="awr">
                <h2 class="entry-title"><a href="http://paleomagazine.com/paleo-blogger-sarah-pope">Blogger Spotlight – Sarah Pope</a></h2>                    
                <a href="http://paleomagazine.com/paleo-blogger-sarah-pope"><img class="fwI" width="630" height="528" src="http://paleomagazine.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/Blogger-Spotlight-Sarah-Pope.jpg" alt="Blogger Spotlight - Sarah Pope" title="Blogger Spotlight - Sarah Pope"></a>
                <p>1. What got you interested in the whole foods lifestyle? The first big motivator was my... <a href="http://paleomagazine.com/paleo-blogger-sarah-pope">more</a></p>
            </div>
        </article>
        <div class="spr"></div>
        <article class="gdl left" style="height: 480px;">
            <div class="awr">
                <h2 class="entry-title"><a href="http://paleomagazine.com/paleo-restaurant-feature-shine-colorado">Paleo Restaurant Feature: Shine Restaurant &amp; Gathering Place</a></h2>                    
                <a href="http://paleomagazine.com/paleo-restaurant-feature-shine-colorado"><img class="fwI" width="730" height="611" src="http://paleomagazine.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/Paleo-Restaurant-Feature-Shine-Restaurant-Gathering-Place1.jpg" alt="Paleo Restaurant Feature: Shine Restaurant &amp; Gathering Place" title="Paleo Restaurant Feature: Shine Restaurant &amp; Gathering Place"></a>
                <p>Shine Restaurant &amp; Gathering Place in Boulder Colorado is owned by triplet sisters, Jennifer,... <a href="http://paleomagazine.com/paleo-restaurant-feature-shine-colorado">more</a></p>
            </div>
        </article>
        <div class="spr"></div>
        <article class="gdl left" style="height: 450px;">
            <div class="awr">
                <h2 class="entry-title"><a href="http://paleomagazine.com/blogger-spotlight-leslie-auman">Blogger Spotlight – Leslie Auman</a></h2>                    
                <a href="http://paleomagazine.com/blogger-spotlight-leslie-auman"><img class="fwI" width="630" height="528" src="http://paleomagazine.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/Leslie-Auman.jpg" alt="Blogger Spotlight - Leslie Auman" title="Blogger Spotlight - Leslie Auman"></a>
                <p>Leslie Auman is the owner and founder of&nbsp;The Whole Life Balance. You can follow her on Instagram,... <a href="http://paleomagazine.com/blogger-spotlight-leslie-auman">more</a></p>
            </div>
        </article>
        <div class="spr"></div>
        <article class="gdl left" style="height: 450px;">
            <div class="awr">
                <h2 class="entry-title"><a href="http://paleomagazine.com/blogger-spotlight-jessica-furniss">Blogger Spotlight – Jessica Furniss</a></h2>                    
                <a href="http://paleomagazine.com/blogger-spotlight-jessica-furniss"><img class="fwI" width="630" height="528" src="http://paleomagazine.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/Blogger-Spotlight-Jessica-Furniss.jpg" alt="Blogger Spotlight - Jessica Furniss" title="Blogger Spotlight - Jessica Furniss"></a>
                <p>Jessica Furniss is the author behind Spiffy Eats &amp; Giggle Water. You can follow her on... <a href="http://paleomagazine.com/blogger-spotlight-jessica-furniss">more</a></p>
            </div>
        </article>
        <div class="spr"></div>
        <article class="gdl left" style="height: 450px;">
            <div class="awr">
                <h2 class="entry-title"><a href="http://paleomagazine.com/blogger-spotlight-ainsley-daschofsky">Blogger Spotlight – Ainsley Daschofsky</a></h2>                    
                <a href="http://paleomagazine.com/blogger-spotlight-ainsley-daschofsky"><img class="fwI" width="730" height="611" src="http://paleomagazine.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/Blogger-Spotlight-–-Ainsley-Daschofsky.jpg" alt="Blogger Spotlight - Ainsley Daschofsky" title="Blogger Spotlight – Ainsley Daschofsky"></a>
                <p>1. What got you interested in the Paleo lifestyle? Oddly, the life train stopped at the low carb... <a href="http://paleomagazine.com/blogger-spotlight-ainsley-daschofsky">more</a></p>
            </div>
        </article>
        <div class="spr"></div>
        <article class="gdl left" style="height: 220px;">
            <div class="awr">
                <h2 class="entry-title"><a href="http://paleomagazine.com/paleo-blogger-chris-kresser">Blogger Spotlight – Chris Kresser</a></h2>                    
                <a href="http://paleomagazine.com/paleo-blogger-chris-kresser"><img class="fwI" width="630" height="528" src="http://paleomagazine.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/Blogger-Spotlight-Chris-Kresser.jpg" alt="Blogger Spotlight - Chris Kresser" title="Blogger Spotlight - Chris Kresser"></a>
                <p>1. What got you interested in the Paleo lifestyle? I suffered from a decade-long, debilitating... <a href="http://paleomagazine.com/paleo-blogger-chris-kresser">more</a></p>
            </div>
        </article>
        <div class="spr"></div>
        <article class="gdl left" style="height: 220px;">
            <div class="awr">
                <h2 class="entry-title"><a href="http://paleomagazine.com/blogger-spotlight-mary-herrington">Blogger Spotlight – Mary Herrington</a></h2>                    
                <a href="http://paleomagazine.com/blogger-spotlight-mary-herrington"><img class="fwI" width="630" height="528" src="http://paleomagazine.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/Blogger-Spotlight-Mary-Herrington.jpg" alt="Blogger Spotlight – Mary Herrington" title="Blogger Spotlight – Mary Herrington"></a>
                <p>1. What got you interested in the Paleo lifestyle? What got me interested in the Paleo lifestyle is... <a href="http://paleomagazine.com/blogger-spotlight-mary-herrington">more</a></p>
            </div>
        </article>
        <div class="spr"></div>
        <article class="gdl left" style="height: 220px;">
            <div class="awr">
                <h2 class="entry-title"><a href="http://paleomagazine.com/blogger-spotlight-danielle-gagnon">Blogger Spotlight – Danielle Gagnon</a></h2>                    
                <a href="http://paleomagazine.com/blogger-spotlight-danielle-gagnon"><img class="fwI" width="630" height="528" src="http://paleomagazine.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/Blogger-Spotlight-Danielle-Gagnon.jpg" alt="Blogger Spotlight - Danielle Gagnon" title="Blogger Spotlight - Danielle Gagnon"></a>
                <p>1. What got you interested in the Paleo lifestyle? I spent most of my college and post-grad years... <a href="http://paleomagazine.com/blogger-spotlight-danielle-gagnon">more</a></p>
            </div>
        </article>
        <div class="spr"></div>
        <article class="gdl left" style="height: 220px;">
            <div class="awr">
                <h2 class="entry-title"><a href="http://paleomagazine.com/natures-palette-for-perfect-health">Nature’s Palette for Perfect Health</a></h2>                    
                <a href="http://paleomagazine.com/natures-palette-for-perfect-health"><img class="fwI" width="630" height="528" src="http://paleomagazine.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/Natures-Palette-for-Perfect-Health.jpg" alt="Nature's Palette for Perfect Health" title="Nature's Palette for Perfect Health"></a>
                <p>Jayson Calton, PhD and Mira Calton, CN are the founders of Calton Nutrition and the authors of... <a href="http://paleomagazine.com/natures-palette-for-perfect-health">more</a></p>
            </div>
        </article>
        <div class="spr"></div>
        <article class="gdl left" style="height: 220px;">
            <div class="awr">
                <h2 class="entry-title"><a href="http://paleomagazine.com/interview-with-george-bryant">Interview with George Bryant – Civilized Caveman</a></h2>                    
                <a href="http://paleomagazine.com/interview-with-george-bryant"><img class="fwI" width="630" height="528" src="http://paleomagazine.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/george-bryant-featured-image.jpg" alt="george bryant featured image" title="george bryant featured image"></a>
                <p>George Bryant of Civilized Caveman is one of our favorite people in Paleo – he’s... <a href="http://paleomagazine.com/interview-with-george-bryant">more</a></p>
            </div>
        </article>
        <div class="spr"></div>
        <article class="gdl left" style="height: 220px;">
            <div class="awr">
                <h2 class="entry-title"><a href="http://paleomagazine.com/paleo-blogger-empowered-sustenance">Favorite Bloggers: Empowered Sustenance</a></h2>                    
                <a href="http://paleomagazine.com/paleo-blogger-empowered-sustenance"><img class="fwI" width="630" height="630" src="http://paleomagazine.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/lauren-geertsen.jpg" alt="lauren geertsen - empowered sustenance" title="lauren geertsen - empowered sustenance"></a>
                <p>The Blog Empowered Sustenance The Blogger Lauren Geertsen Her Story Lauren, although still very... <a href="http://paleomagazine.com/paleo-blogger-empowered-sustenance">more</a></p>
            </div>
        </article>
        <div class="spr"></div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
        <div class="awr ctr pgn">
            <span class="page-numbers current">1</span>
            <a class="page-numbers" href="http://paleomagazine.com/paleo-websites-bloggers/page/2/">2</a>
            <a class="next page-numbers" href="http://paleomagazine.com/paleo-websites-bloggers/page/2/">Next »</a>
        </div>
        <div class="bspr"></div>
        <div class="clear" style="width: 100%; height: 1px; margin: 0;"></div>
        <div class="custom-category-description"></div>
        <div class="clear" style="width: 100%; height: 1px; margin: 0;"></div>
        <div class="category-page-bottom-optins">
            <div>
                <a target="_blank" onclick="ga('send', 'event', 'Category Bottom Optin', 'Click', '7-Day Challenge', {'nonInteraction': 1});">
                    <span class="tve-leads-two-step-trigger tl-2step-trigger-25371" style="display: inline;"><img src="http://paleomagazine.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/challenge-optin.jpeg" height="300" width="300"></span>
                </a>
                <img alt="GA Pixel" width="0" height="0" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAP///////yH5BAEKAAEALAAAAAABAAEAAAICTAEAOw==" onload="ga('send', 'event', 'Category Bottom Optin', 'Impression', '7-Day Challenge', {'nonInteraction': 1});">
            </div>
            <div>
                <a target="_blank" onclick="ga('send', 'event', 'Category Bottom Optin', 'Click', 'Favorite 11 Recipes', {'nonInteraction': 1});"><span class="tve-leads-two-step-trigger tl-2step-trigger-16874" style="display: inline;"><img src="http://paleomagazine.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/favorite-paleo-recipes.jpg" height="300" width="300"></span></a>
                <img alt="GA Pixel" width="0" height="0" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAP///////yH5BAEKAAEALAAAAAABAAEAAAICTAEAOw==" onload="ga('send', 'event', 'Category Bottom Optin', 'Impression', 'Favorite 11 Recipes', {'nonInteraction': 1});">
            </div>
            <div>
                <a target="_blank" onclick="ga('send', 'event', 'Category Bottom Optin', 'Click', 'Meal Plan', {'nonInteraction': 1});"><span class="tve-leads-two-step-trigger tl-2step-trigger-25517" style="display: inline;"><img src="http://paleomagazine.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/meal-plan-optin.jpeg" height="300" width="300"></span></a>
                <img alt="GA Pixel" width="0" height="0" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAP///////yH5BAEKAAEALAAAAAABAAEAAAICTAEAOw==" onload="ga('send', 'event', 'Category Bottom Optin', 'Impression', 'Meal Plan', {'nonInteraction': 1});">
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</div>
```

Any help or suggestions here is greatly appreciated.

Comment: More of your code would help in finding an answer.  Is there any way you can give enough to reproduce your issue?

I tried using the code you provided, but your flex-container is missing from your html.  


I also tried using the code from the site you provided, but without more context it proved to be more effort than I have time to put in.

Comment: @DavidMann - I'm updating my post to include all of the code.  (I had no objection to including it all - just thought it would make it unnecessarily long.)  And I thought some changes I made yesterday had solved the issue, but they have not.

Answer (score 1):

Define [`width`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img#attr-width) and [`height`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img#attr-height) attributes on the image. This should help the browser [render page correctly before loading image content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4287811/specifying-image-dimensions-in-html-vs-css-for-page-loading#4287847).

---

Example HTML would be changed to the following

```
<article class="gdl left" style="height: 656px;">
  <div class="awr">
    <h2 class="entry-title">
      <a href="http://paleomagazine.com/paleo-cinnamon-raisin-toast-recipe">10-Minute Paleo Cinnamon Raisin Toast Recipe</a>
    </h2>
    <div class="fwit">
      <a class="pst" href="http://paleomagazine.com/paleo-cinnamon-raisin-toast-recipe">
        <img class="fwI"
             src="http://paleomagazine.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/Paleo-Cinnamon-Raisin-Toast-Recipe-1.jpg"
             width="800"
             height="1200"
             alt="Paleo Cinnamon Raisin Toast Recipe #paleo #recipe http://paleomagazine.com/paleo-cinnamon-raisin-toast-recipe"
             title="Paleo Cinnamon Raisin Toast Recipe #paleo #recipe http://paleomagazine.com/paleo-cinnamon-raisin-toast-recipe">
      </a>
    </div>
    This is a quick and easy Paleo cinnamon raisin toast recipe. It’s perfect as a delicious...<a href="http://paleomagazine.com/paleo-cinnamon-raisin-toast-recipe">more</a>
  </div>
</article>
```

Comment: I thought about this - but I don't know how to do it, because the width of the image (and therefore the height) is dependent on the width of the container element, which is defined through its flexbox properties.

Comment: @JeremyHendon those attributes are exactly for that: informing the browser about image's **pixel dimensions** before it's fetched!

Comment: Yeah - I don't mean to be obtuse about it.  I just don't know how to get them calculated before the browser calculates the width of the parent flexbox.  The same image could be 150px wide or 300px wide, depending on the screen size.  But I also can't use vw or anything, because the image width is based on the width of the flex-box, which isn't directly proportional to the screen width, particularly since on smaller screens, the number of items in a row will decrease.

Comment: I don't want to sound rude either! I think an example will be best: consider HTML `<img src='something.png' width='4000' height='3000' alt='' />` and CSS `img{width:100%;display:block}` and when the screen is 400 pixels wide *the image will correctly be 300 pixels tall*. Element's `style` attr === CSS rule, `width`&`height` is *not*.

Comment: Along with a few other minor changes, I ended up including the original width and height, and it does seem to have fixed the issue.  The included width and height are bigger than the displayed image - which I initially thought would be a problem, but turned out not to be.

Comment: I thought this had fixed the issue, but even with the image width and height inserted, the issue still persists.